# Build ant jenkins

Tags: android, ant, jenkins

When I execute task in Jenkins with android project, I have problems with GetTargetTask:

```
ant/build.xml:533: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.loadPlatforms(SdkManager.java:386)
at com.android.sdklib.SdkManager.createManager(SdkManager.java:151)
at com.android.ant.GetTargetTask.execute(GetTargetTask.java:120)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
```

But when I execute Ant direct in project folder I don´t have errors...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jenkins permissions!!!

I was trying with user that hadn´t permissions on jenkins workspace